# My variable declaration is not detected even if i declare it right before

Tags: c#

```
namespace Genoclon_BB.BDD
{
public class ConexionBDD
{
    int hola = 1;
    hola = 2;
}
}
```

Even if i declare my variable, when i try to use it the next time, is not available

Comment: How do you try to use it? This code example is not correct and cannot be compiled

Comment: because what you have declared is a field, not a variable. The difference is, field is at the class level, while variables are inside method

Comment: The code example you gave us is not correct and does not have any meaning. Sorry, but we can't help you with this.
If possible, please provide more detail or at least give us your real snippet code, it will be better.
At last, happy learning, C# is really fun and I do like it.

Comment: @Juan Since you're just starting, I suggest not to go into the details of what's the different between a field and a variable. As j.v suggested in his answer, play around with those variables first. Also, I would recommend to you to go through a tutorial and do side by side coding.

Answer (score 1):

```
namespace Genoclon_BB.BDD
{
public class ConexionBDD
{
    public int hoola = 2; //<=This is a field
    hoola = 3; //Cannot do this
    public void SomeMethod(){
        int hola = 1; <= This is a variable
        hola = 2;
        hoola = 3; //Can do this
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make console application and play with variables in Main...

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         int hola = 1;
         hola = 2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new class to use it and give it value.

```
    class Program
    {

        public  class ConexionBDD
        {
            public int hola { get; set; }
            public ConexionBDD()
            {
                this.hola = 2;
            }
        }

         static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var tmp = new ConexionBDD();
            Console.WriteLine(tmp.hola);
            tmp.hola = 111;
            Console.WriteLine(tmp.hola);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```